# Xcode 9.4.1 Storyboard scene blue border around components

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xcode9

[image]

This is how I see my storyboard scenes. Why does it shows so? How to disable this to see the constraint errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Please do following steps to get resolved!!!**

1. Open storyboard
2. Go to Editor
3. Uncheck all options expect following

   - Show Constraints
   - Show Device Bezels
   - Show Placeholder Backgrounds

> Please check attached image to make sure.

Hope this will solve your issue :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Editor** -> **Canvas** -> Uncheck **Show Layout Rectangles** & Uncheck **Show Bounds Rectangles**

[image]